# Proper title of Zuse patent submission Z23624

Tags: history, computer, germany, german

Consider the Zuse computer patent submission Z23624, available from the [Konrad Zuse Internet Archive](http://zuse.zib.de/pdfs).

The title of the ZIA ID 0177 in http://zuse.zib.de/pdfs is

> Patentanmeldung Z23624 "Rechenmaschine"

However, if you look into the PDF, the title is

> Patentanmeldung Z23624 (Z1)*

with a footnote

> ZuP 005/012. Version 1, Abbildungen fehlen.

Why is there a difference?  What's the actual title?  And what does "ZuP 005/012, Version 1" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have no special knowledge in this, but can use Google to translate German to English. "Patentanmeldung" means patent application and "Rechenmaschine" means mechanical calculator. It seems obvious to me that "Patentanmeldung Z23624 (Z1)" is simply the patent application number and that the actual application title is "Rechenmaschine". As for "Abbildungen fehlen", that means illustrations are missing.

Comment: The Z33624 format doesn’t seem to correspond to the format used for German applications currently. It might have been different in the 1930s